# Gradle: com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 and com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:24.0.0 must use the exact same version

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

On the following 'complie' in my Gradle file:

```
dependencies {   
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1' 
}
```

I have got the following error:

> > *All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
> >     versions 25.3.1, 24.0.0. Examples include
> >     com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 and
> >     com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:24.0.0.
> >
> > There are some
> >     combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are
> >     incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
> >     compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
> >     the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
> >     targetSdkVersion.)*

But I don't find any use reference to this 'animated-vector-drawable' library in my project (used the search tool).

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks !

Comment: can you put all your gradle file here Regis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this line your app gradle file

```
compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
```

Comment: Thanks ! Has also to add : compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.3.1'

Answer (score 0):

you need to set all gradle version should be same version